# How to export Instrument's CPU Monitor's statistics to be usable in Excel or Numbers?

Tags: iphone, xcode, statistics, cpu-usage, instruments

I require statistics of CPU Load of my iPhone apps. I am trying to use Instrument to see the CPU Load, but all I see in Instrument program is rendered graphs. I need these statistics data in raw numbers so that I can put all of them on graphs using Excel or Numbers. Is there a way to export these data in such a way? Or do I need other programs to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export them as CSV. I have done so before and it works great, however I am not sure the CPU Load instrument supports csv export. See the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/SavingTraceTemplates/SavingTraceTemplates.html).:

> Exporting Track Data Instruments lets
>   you export trace data to a
>   comma-separated value (CSV) file
>   format. This simple data file format
>   is supported by many applications. For
>   example, you might save your trace
>   data in this format so that you can
>   import it into a spreadsheet
>   application.
>
> To save your trace data to a CSV file,
>   select the instrument whose data you
>   want to export and choose Instrument >
>   Export Data for: .
>   Instruments exports the data for the
>   most recent run of that instrument.
>
> Note: Not all instruments support
>   exporting to the CSV file format.